# Does DataNucleus persist JodaTime's DateTime differently with a non-local timezone?

Tags: datanucleus

Is Joda Time's DateTime class persisted differently when given in the UTC timezone? The timestamps look unusual (may be all zeroes).

Joda Time created them just fine with `new DateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC)`. Are they persisted in PostgreSQL in an unfamiliar format?

```
"2012-09-02 23:43:44.642-07"
"2012-09-03 00:05:01.517-07"
"2012-09-03 00:10:30.704-07"
"1969-12-31 16:00:00-08"
"2012-09-03 00:23:40.556-07"
"1969-12-31 16:00:00-08"
"1969-12-31 16:00:00-08"
"1969-12-31 16:00:00-08"
```

The versions are:

1. postgresql-9.1-901.jdbc4.jar
2. DataNucleus Core/RDBMS 3.1.1
3. DataNucleus Joda Time 3.1.0-release.

Thank you.

Comment: Obviously you are persisting them in String form, so perhaps ask Jodatime why it is generating those strings from the toString() method?

Comment: @DataNucleus, DateTime prints correctly with toString(), but the PostgreSQL field type is "timestamp with time zone", which sounds incompatible. Can I choose the field type?

Comment: @DataNucleus, the field persists correctly when I specify `@Column(jdbcType="VARCHAR", length=40)`. Why does it not work with the SQL timestamp?

Comment: FWIW (looking at the code) with TIMESTAMP it uses "new Timestamp(((DateTime)value).getMillis())" to store it, and "((Timestamp)datastoreValue).getTime()" to retrieve it.

Comment: @DataNucleus, your code is obviously correct. The problem was in the JDBC4 driver. Upgrading to 'postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar' solved the problem. I looked for relevant commit logs, but could not find any. As a side note, [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pgsql.interfaces.jdbc/4QBtK6-msrk) points out that the jar for 901-1 on Maven central is actually version 902.

Comment: good to know; I'd been using 9.1-901.jdbc4 from some time ago so never hit the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As detailed in the comments, the problem was solved by upgrading the JDBC4 driver for PostgreSQL to 'postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar'.